# Facebook Spring Security - Redirect to the page where user called/last page accessed by the user

Tags: facebook, grails, spring-security, grails-plugin

I have a Grails application with the Facebook Authentication for Spring Security plugin. In "Resources.groovy", I have the next bean:

```
// Redirect to this URL when authentication fails
redirectFailureHandler(SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler) {
    defaultFailureUrl = '/'
}
```

When an error in the Facebook login appears, the application redirects to "/". But I want to know if it's possible redirect to the last page visited by the user or what it is the same, the page where it was called the Facebook login.

Thanks